# TypeScript fails to check React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

For example I got the following component:

```
const Component = ({
  messages,
}: {
  messages: ({ text: string; } | undefined)[];
}) => {
  return (
    <>
      {messages.map((message) => (
        <div key={message.text}>
          {message.text}
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

It doesn't throw errors when I use it like this:

```
// First example
<Component messages={[ someBoolean ? "text 1" : undefined, "text 2", ]} />
```

However, it throws errors when I use it like this:

```
// Second example
const messages = [ someBoolean ?  "text 1" : undefined, "text 2" ]
<Component messages={messages} />

// Third example
<Component messages={[ someBoolean ?  "text 1" : undefined, "text 2" ] as const} />
```

Why the first example doesn't' throw errors? Should I add some to the tsconfig to catch this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be an error in every places where you use the `messages` array.
The reason is of the difference in types `{ text: string; }[]` vs `string[]`.

TypeScript has an internal cache.

For VisualStudioCode IDE press `F1`, type `TypeScript: Restart TS server` and run that command. In several seconds you should see your errors.

For other IDEs just try to restart the application.